# Хочу использовать матрицу из одного метода в другом

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы

Создал метод в котором была создана матрица,теперь хочу использовать полученную матрицу в другом методе, но не получается. Как это можно сделать?

```
private static void twoDemensionalArray(){
System.out.println("Enter the size of mass: ") ;   
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
  int m = scanner.nextInt();
  int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int [] [] arr = new int [m] [n];
    for(int i = 0; i< m; i++){ 
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
    Random random = new Random();
    arr [i] [j] = random.nextInt(10);
     System.out.print(arr [i] [j] + " ") ;
     } 
       System.out.println();          
   }       
}
```

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? Использовать в другой функции?

Comment: В новом методе не могу вызвать эту матрицу чтобы работать с ней.

Comment: Сейчас напишу ответом

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы где-то в вашем коде вызвать функцию, которая вычитает из консоли ввод пользователя и вернет вам матрицу, нужно сделать так:

Для начала объявляем функцию:

```
public static int[][] twoDimensionalArray() {

}
```

Внутри функции пишем все, что у вас уже написано, только в самом конце функции добавляем строчку:

```
public static int[][] twoDimensionalArray() {
    // Код функции
    ....
    int[][] arr = ...
    ....

    // Вот эта строчка, возвращаем результат
    return arr; 
}
```

Теперь в любом месте вашего кода мы можем вызвать эту функцию и сохранить результат её работы в переменную:

```
// Где-то в коде
int[][] arr = twoDimensionalArray();
```

Как-то так

Answer (score 2):

Дополню ответы предыдущих участников.

У Вас в одном методе выполняется три действия

1. Вы запрашиваете у пользователя размер массива
2. Вы создаете массив и заполняете его случайными числами
3. Вы выводите созданный массив на экран

Это крайне неудачное архитектурное решение. Гораздо правильнее написать три разных метода. А может, даже, имеет смысл создать отдельный класс `Matrix`

```
class Matrix {
  private int[][] arr;
  public Matrix(int m, int n) {
    int[][] arr = new int[m][n];
  }

  public void fillRandom() {
    Random random = new Random();  // генератор нужно создавать один раз
    for(int i = 0; i < getRows(); i++) { 
      for(int j = 0; j < getCols(); j++) {
        set(i, j, random.nextInt(10));
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < getRows(); i++) { 
      for(int j = 0; j < getCols(); j++) {
        res.append(get(i, j)).append(' ');
      }
      res.append('\n');
    }
    return res.toString();
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.print(toString());
  }

  public int getRows() {
    return arr.length;
  }

  public int getCols() {
    return arr[0].length;
  }

  public int get(int row, int col) {
    return arr[row][col];
  }

  public void set(int row, int col, int val) {
    arr[row][col] = val;
  }
}
```

Тогда Ваш метод перепишется так

```
private static void twoDemensionalArray(){
  System.out.println("Enter the size of mass: ") ;   
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
  int m = scanner.nextInt();
  int n = scanner.nextInt();
  Matrix m = new Matrix(m, n);
  m.fillRandom();
  m.print();
}
```

Или, если Вы хотите вернуть из него значение

```
private static Matrix twoDemensionalArray(){
  ..........
  m.print();
  return m;
}
```

В этом же классе, вы можете определить операции сложения, умножения, транспонирования... матриц

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] myArr = twoDemensionalArray();
    method(myArr);
}

private static void method(int[][] arr){
    for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]));
    }
}

private static int[][] twoDemensionalArray(){
    System.out.println("Enter the size of mass: ") ;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    int m = scanner.nextInt();
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int [] [] arr = new int [m] [n];
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i< m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            arr [i] [j] = random.nextInt(10);
            System.out.print(arr [i] [j] + " ") ;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return arr;
}
```